# Can I add remote configuration to an amp component, or load a component remotely?

Tags: amp-html

Some amp components, such as amp-link-rewriter take json configuration like this:

```html
<amp-link-rewriter layout="nodisplay">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "output": "https://visit.foo.net?pid=110&url=${href}&cid=${customerId}",
            "section": [
                "#product-listing-1",
                "#product-listing-2",
            ],
            "attribute": {
                "href": "`((?!(https:\/\/skip\.com)).)*`",
                "id": "comments",
                "class": "sidebar",
                "rel": "(?!(skip))*",
            },
            "vars": {
                "customerId": "12345"
            }
        }
    </script>
</amp-link-rewriter>
```

I have a static site where I need to provide dynamic configuration to this kind of component without changing the html of the page itself.

I've tried using a src attribute like this:

```html
<amp-link-rewriter layout="nodisplay">
    <script type="application/json" src="https://example.com/foo.json"></script>
</amp-link-rewriter>
```

Which doesn't work and isn't an allowed by link-rewriter in the first place.

I've also tried loading the whole component in an amp-script, but that didn't seem to work either. I doubt it would work given that amp components are probably all loaded and processed at the beginning of execution or something. I didn't try very hard though so if that's actually a viable solution let me know.

I'm aware that this kind of goes against the whole "predictable performance" philosophy of amp, but it'd be nice to have a solution for this sort of situation, since I can't imagine it being too uncommon. Maybe something like additional "cached resources" that can be specified per site and updated occasionally separate from the cached amp pages themselves.

Any suggestions or alternatives to consider are very welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using Front Matter Data ?

Comment: @StefanyNewman I tried googling that but all I got was https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/contribute/contribute-documentation/formatting/

Do you have a link or a term that'll give more helpful results in google?

Comment: Sorry I meant something like this https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/ Which static site generator are you using ? (since you mentioned your site is static)

Comment: @StefanyNewman The generator being used unfortunately doesn't matter. You can consider it as though I'm just manually writing an html file and sticking it in S3, then throwing away the key. Once I put the html up, I can't change it, and I can't change what's generating it. That's why something dynamic has to happen after the page is fetched, it can't happen beforehand.